# No SDK listed in the installation window for Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-debug

I was installing Android Studio Hedgehog (latest version), from the official website. After downloading, Android Studio was asking for a SDK. I checked my directories and did not find the folder. I attampted to re-download to see what is downloaded and installed in the process and it did not have the SDK listed.

Can anyone help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIAR8.png)

An SDK installed for developing apps

Comment: The icon sdk manager from android studio is available ?

Answer (score -1):

In the Android studio, click on the settings icon at the top right corner, and a menu will open, select the SDK manager option from there. A new window will open listing all the SDKs with their statuses, pick the one you want and click ok. It will first download and then install on your system.